# varnish vhost specific config?

Tags: virtualhost, varnish

(varnish-4.1.1 revision 66bb824)

Many relatedposts exist on this so my apologies.  what is the best practice if you need to use varnish with two sites with different requirements?  Ive seen approaches with if statements that are unclear.  if all my defaul.vcl contains is an if site include specific.vcl, it doesn't work.  I found a blog recommending renaming all the sun vcl_ routines and calling a vhost specific one.  Maybe a giant monolithic unmanagble config with if statements in every every v host in each sub vcl_

I get the feeling I'm missing the forest for the trees.  surely a "universal config" isn't possible that handles all situations?
I feel like I'm misunderstanding the situation or stumbling on some seriously inelegant anti=patterns (maybe both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way and you have to make use of include files one way or another. Putting a bunch of include statements into the main file is counter-productive since you will end up with a large VCL with dozens of `if`s, that is hard to manage.

I've posted an article how you should be managing [Varnish virtual hosts](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-virtual-hosts) in a clutter-free way, which seems to be the only clean approach. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: As a varnish newbie this is pretty dense but appears to address my concerns in a more elegant way.  I didn't see this article prior to this, much thanks!